# Does an insulated vs not insulated icecream tub melt the same speed in an environment without gravity(relatively very close large body really)?

Tags: thermodynamics

Two ice cream tubs on earth. One covered with a cloth(or whatever insulator) one without. The one insulated melts slower due to conduction heat transfer difference etc before it interacts with the air and convection. If they were in an environment without convection(mostly, given it works with gravitty) say a 'zero gravity space station' and you had those same ice cream tub conditions; would they then melt basically at the same speed?

Comment: why do you think convection will affect heat exchange speed if there is no transfer of mass between the interior and the exterior?

Comment: An insulated system means that there is no exchange of energy (heat in this case) between it and the environment.

Comment: I don't mean something perfectly insulated hence the cloth example. Something that slows the rate merely. I am guessing without convention that the heat dissipation on the surface of the insulated is going to render the difference in conductive heat from the  icecream through blanket vs not essentially moot